# Fatal Exception: main android error

Tags: android

I've been trying to create a random number generator for android but i can't seem to get the app to run on the virtual device without crashing.

**Here are the errors:**

```
07-01 11:37:00.768: D/AndroidRuntime(2022): Shutting down VM
07-01 11:37:00.808: W/dalvikvm(2022): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d5cb20)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022): Process: com.bruinstech.numbergen, PID: 2022
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bruinstech.numbergen/com.bruinstech.numbergen.MainAcitivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.bruinstech.numbergen.MainAcitivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bruinstech.numbergen-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.bruinstech.numbergen-1, /system/lib]]
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.bruinstech.numbergen.MainAcitivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bruinstech.numbergen-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.bruinstech.numbergen-1, /system/lib]]
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
07-01 11:37:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2022):     ... 11 more
```

My **MainActivity.java:**
package com.bruinstech.numbergen;

```
import java.util.Random;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText nu1;
EditText nu2;
TextView number;
Button button1;
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v){
            int y = Integer.parseInt(nu1.getText().toString());
            int x = Integer.parseInt(nu2.getText().toString());
            number.setText("Random Number: " + randomGenerator(x, y));
        }
    });


    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView1);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

public static int randomGenerator(int y, int x) {


    Random rand = new Random();

    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((y - x) + 1) + y;

    return randomNum;
}

}
```

And my **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/value"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/value"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nu2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/no2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nu1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/no1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/but" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appraicated

Comment: please post your manifest too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

`com.bruinstech.numbergen.MainAcitivity` should be `com.bruinstech.numbergen.MainActivity` instead (in general, it must match your class name).

Comment: Well i feel like an idiot... Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @bruins1993 Don't worry, we have all encountered these kind of problems ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Check the path for the MainActivity you provided there, correct it and your issue should be resolved.